# Command 'cut' doesn't show last column CSV

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv

I've created a CSV from shell. Then I need to filter the information by column. I used this command:

```
$cut -d ';' -f 12,22 big_file.csv
```

The input looks like:

```
ACT;XXXXXX;MCD;881XXXX;881017XXXXXX;ABCD;BMORRR;GEN;88XXXXXXXXXX;00000;01;2;000008608008602;AAAAAAAAAAA;0051;;;;;;093505;
ACT;XXXXXX;MCD;881XXXX;881017XXXXXX;ABCD;BMORRR;GEN;88XXXXXXXXXX;00000;01;3;000008608008602;AAAAAAAAAAA;0051;;;;;;085000;anl@mail.com
```

The output is:

```
ID CLIENT;email
00000xxxxxxxxx
00000000xxxxxx;anl@mail.com
```

As you can see, the last column does not appear (note, that the semicolon is missing in the first line). I want this:

```
ID CLIENT;email
00000xxxxxxxxx;
00000000xxxxxx;anl@mail.com
```

I have another CSV file with information and it works. I've reviewed the csv and the columns exist.

Comment: What does the input look like? Is the trouble that you want a trailing semicolon even if the input line has no column 22?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Ok. I've added an input.

Comment: Hmm for me `echo "a;b;" | cut -d';' -f1,3` does output `a;`. Are you sure the line with no email actually has enough semicolons?

Comment: Where from is the `ID CLIENT;email` in the output? Can't duplicate, there are 21 fields in the input file. Don't you want `-f12,21` ? That could be it. Maybe you have some `\r` characters in your input. So the `;` is there but behind the `0`

Comment: I think wich the problem is with the 'end of line', because I tested with a CSV created from excel, and then with the mine. The outputs are differents.

Comment: @KamilCuk I could try it

Comment: @HenningMakholm I've reviewed, everything is fine. Bellow, your answer was excellent

Comment: My input was wrong. I've changed it. I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to make `cut` do this. The next step up in expressivity is `awk`, which does it easily:

```
$ cat testfile
one;two;three;four
1;2;3
first;second
only
$ awk -F';' '{ OFS=FS; print $1, $3 }' < testfile
one;three
1;3
first;
only;
$
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't get the semicolon in the output of your second line, because your second line contains just 21 fields (the first contains 23 fields).
You can check that using:

```
(cat bigfile.csv | tr -d -c ";\n" ; echo "1234567890123456789012") | cat -n | grep -v -E ";{22}"
```

This will output all lines from `bigfile.txt` with less than 22 semicolons along with the corresponding line numbers.

To fix that, you can add a bunch of empty fields at the end of each line and pipe the result to cut like this:

```
sed -e's|^\(.*\)|\1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;|g' bigfile.csv | cut -d ';' -f 12,22 | cut -d ';' -f 12,22
```

The result is:

```
XXXXXXXXYYY;XXXNNN
XXXXYYYYXXXXX;
```

Comment: No, I just want 12 and 22.

Comment: So specify it with a comma. `-f 12,22`

Comment: @EderArmandoAnilloLora: ok, I see, you are missing the one semicolon. I update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My copy from file was wrong. Sorry, I've modified the post. I've used the @Henning Makholm answer and It's works.